# No route matches [POST] "/additem" Trying to create a crud project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

This is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'maincontroller#mainview', as: 'mainview'


  get 'additem' => 'maincontroller#additem', as:  'additem'

  resources :maincontroller
end
```

This is my controller

```
class MaincontrollerController < ApplicationController

  def item
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def additem
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private 

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:item_name, :item_desc)
  end
end
```

This is my additem.html.erb

```
<h1>Item</h1>
<%= form_for :post, url: additem_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Item_Name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field(:Item_Name, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Item_Description %><br>   
    <%= f.text_area(:item_desc, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit({:class => 'btn btn-primary'})%>
  </p>
<%end%>
```

Comment: What is your error message? Can you describe more clearly what yourdesired outcome is?

Comment: I'm just trying to input an item name and a description

Comment: Error its self give you ans 
`get 'additem' => 'maincontroller#additem', as:  'additem'` change this line to
`post 'additem' => 'maincontroller#additem', as:  'additem'`

Comment: I already tried that but another error occur. It says "No route matches [GET] "/add_item""

Comment: I'd suggest to put the actual question you want to have answered as the last words on your post, instead of having it scattered over title and general domain knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the default method when you submit a form is `POST`.

So, You just need to change the HTTP verb to `post`

```
post 'additem' => 'maincontroller#additem', as:  'additem'
```

And you can check the routes by:

```
rake routes
```

Comment: I already changed that but another error occur. it's like im in the loop of errors. lol

Comment: How did you get this error "No route matches [GET] "/add_item"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

in routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'maincontroller#mainview', as: 'mainview'


  get 'new_item' => 'maincontroller#new_item', as:  'new_item'
  post 'add_item' => 'maincontroller#add_item', as:  'add_item'

  resources :maincontroller
end
```

in controller

```
class MaincontrollerController < ApplicationController

  def item
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new_item
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
  end

  def add_item
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private 

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:item_name, :item_desc)
  end
end
```

in your view

```
<h1>Item</h1>
<%= form_for :post, url: add_item_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :item_Name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field(:item_name, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :item_description %><br>   
    <%= f.text_area(:item_desc, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit({:class => 'btn btn-primary'})%>
  </p>
<%end%>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This error occur after i change the codes "uninitialized constant MaincontrollerController::Post
Extracted source (around line #12):

This is my line 12 "@post = Post.new(post_params)"

Comment: did you generate the post model?

Comment: What do you mean by updating the route into post to add_item method.

Comment: Ye, I already tried that. It says "No route matches [GET] "/add_item""

Comment: try to change the form into <%= form_for :post, url: add_item_path, method: :post do |f| %>